# Sort LifeEvents chronologically

Tags: financial-services-cloud

I'm just starting out with FSC. I would like to sort the events in the LifeEvent component by chronological order. From [this module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/insurance-agent-console-for-sales-and-service/create-a-new-life-event?trail_id=deliver-personalized-insurance-service-with-financial-services-cloud), I gather :

> Notice that the events are not exactly in chronological order. That’s because admins can customize the order of life events any way they want based on business requirements. The powers-that-be at Cumulus wanted all life events across policyholders to appear in a set order. For example, childbirth is always third from right. This is to help agents who typically deal with a large volume of policies on a daily basis quickly scan the Life Events component and find the information they need without much effort.

I understand that they are not ***necessarily*** in chronological order, but that admins can customise the order. Can anyone guide me to where the configuration is done ? We have tried looking in setup to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting which Admin can change so that Life Event Component shows events in chronological order by default.

Admin can customize the order and determine which type of Life Events comes first which second and so on.

Steps to update default order of life events is
Setup -> Object Manager -> Person Life Event Object -> Fields & Relationships -> EventType Field -> ReOrder button in Event Type Picklist Values section -> Change the order of values.